# Rotating circle while moving on a line by a linear speeds relation

Tags: geometry, curves, geometric-construction

I'm searching for a curve identification which comes from the trace of point $P:(0,a+r)$ on  circle $C: x^2+(y-a)^2=r^2$ when the circle rotates while its center moves on yAxis toward the cordinate center and the speed of circle's rotation has a linear relation with the speed of circle's center moving.

If we set the linear relation between $y_c$ the vertical element of the center of circle $C$ when moves along Yaxis ,and circle's rotation angle $\gamma$ in radian as follows: $\gamma=\pi(1-\frac{y_c}{a})$ then it would not be hard to find the curve's graph by using simple trigonometric relations :

$y=r\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{r})^2}+ a-(\frac{a}{\pi})\arcsin{\frac{-x}{r}}$

for example the graph below shows the trace for $a=10,r=9$:[image]

What are the characteristics of such curve?

Dose anybody know  whether we can draw this curve with usage of a string (or a marked string ) or not?

Comment: When $a=r$, you notably get a [brachistochrone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve), which can be drawn by tracing a point on the perimeter of a circle as it rolls on a line. For $a\neq r$, I imagine it can be drawn by rolling a circle of radius $a$ along a line $x=a$, while tracing the an arm/hole a distance $r$ from the center.

Comment: @Angelica well, how did you reach the brachistochrone curve when $a=r$, sorry I didn't get your mean of an arm/hole notion.

Comment: suppose you cut out a paper circle of radius $a$ and roll it along a line. Then poke a hole a distance $r$ from the center (this may require you to tape an extra strip of paper on the circle for $r>a$). If you trace the hole as you roll the circle, then you get your shape.

Comment: @Angelica it seems you mean trochoid curve: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochoid#%3A%7E%3Atext%3DIn_geometry%2C_a_trochoid_%28from%2Crolls_along_a_straight_line.?wprov=sfla1
but It seems this curve doesn't match the trochoid you've mentioned because of the different speed rotation of my circle with radius $r$ and your circle with radius $a$ when you roll it on line $x=a$.